# Test for gaps in range

Tags: c#

I need to test if some objects inside a database fill a specific range, i.e 0-999.

I'm using C# and I've created a generic class using IComparable to test for the intersection. This works fine but I need to invert and find all the gaps that I have in this interval.

My database objects have start and end properties, that are integers. I can find where are the gaps, but I need to cluster them to create the missing pieces.

```
foreach (var interval in intervals)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 999; i++)
    {
        if (Range<int>.Intersects(interval,new Range<int>(i,i)))
            continue;
        else
            doesNotIntersect.Add(i);
    }
}
```

With this code I have a pretty list of "holes". What I'm trying to do now is to group these values, but I find that my solution is not optimal and certainly not elegant.

I've read about BitArrays, but how can they help me? I wish that from a list of ranges I can find the gaps in a fixed range. If we are talking about a line, I need basically the result of fixed - intervals.

I can only use .NET to solve this. I have a large piece of middleware and this process of validation will occur several times a day, so I prefer not having to go through middleware and then databasr to solve.

Let me try to create a picture

> Fixed range that needs to be filled
>
> 111111111
>
> Ranges that objects provided
>
> 101100001
>
> Ranges that need to be filled
>
> 010011110

This is my range object:

```
public class Range<T> where T : IComparable
{
    public T Start { get; set; }
    public T End { get; set; }

    public Range(T start, T end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public static bool Intersects(Range<T> left,Range<T> right)
    {
        if (left.Start.CompareTo(right.Start) == 0)
            return true;

        if (left.Start.CompareTo(right.Start) > 0)
        {
            return left.Start.CompareTo(right.End) <= 0;
        }

        return right.Start.CompareTo(left.End) <= 0;
    }
}
```

I need to find gaps in start end points, instead of continous intervals.

Help?

Comment: Do you need the intervals in terms of pairs of startpoint/endpoint or do you just need all the integers that don't appear in that range in order? ie you just want the result to be 1,4,5,6,7 or do you want it to be 1-1, 4-7?

Comment: Also what is your Range object? I can't seem to find it anywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
00000000000000000000000000000
|              |
8:00           9:00
```

Suppose every '0' in the bitarray represents a time unit(second, hour etc.)
Start looping the intervals and set bits according to start & end values.
Now you will have something like this

```
11110001111110001111000111000
```

The '0' are your grouped gaps

Comment: @George Why do you need it? You should do bitwise ops like `and` `xor` etc. Or are you asking `bitArray.Set(index,bool)`?

Comment: Humn, thats true LB. That might do it!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SQL for that, if the integer value could be represented by entity. Then just create a table with single column seq where are all values from 0 to 999 then using left outer join, join the table with that entity and select only those id where entity is null.

Example query should look like this.

```
SELECT ts.seq
 FROM sequenceTable ts LEFT OUTER JOIN sourceTable st ON ts.seq = st.entity
WHERE st.entity is null;
```

You could use the row num to create column seq of table seauenceTable.

--EDIT

As the solution should be in CLR, you can use use Collections, create a List with values from 0 to 999, then remove all from then intervals.

Next solution is using a boolean array. Create array with the proper length (999 in this case), then iterate through the  intervals, and use interval as index where value true for it in boolean array, then just iterate once again over that array and the missing intervals will be  represented by index where value is false.

Comment: thanks a cool solution, but i'll update my post. I can't use raw sql to solve. It has to be a pure CLR solution.